# Is a given number a prime or not, if not output all its divisors

Tags: c#, primes, factors

The main part of my code is working, the only thing that doesn't work is the output of all its divisors. My result if it's not a prime should be like this:
Input -> 4
Output -> false 1 2 4

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Type your number: ");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int a = 0, i;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
        a++;
    }
}

if (a == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("false" + i);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It's a better learning experience if you do your own homework, rather than get others to do it for you.

Comment: `i` is an integer (number), how do you expect it to contain 1, _2, **and** 4_?

Comment: Either repeat the checking loop in the `true` block, this time outputting the divisors, or else use a table to store them where you increment the count.

Comment: @PaulF Thanks for the advice really appreciate it ;). I wouldn't ask this question if my program skills would be better.

Comment: Did you try the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding.

Comment: Then you really ought to be discussing what you don't understand with your teacher - rather than presenting answers that somebody else has come up with for you.

Comment: It was just a simple answer which would have helped me a lot. I searched more than 3 hours just for this ```c# divisors.Add(i);```. I am not following lessons but hey if you think you figured it al out fine by me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print all the divisors, you'll need to gather them up in a collection of some sort – a list of integers, here.

In addition, all integers are divisible by `1`, so you don't want to start there; neither do you want to end at `n`, since `n % n == 0`.

```cs
var divisors = new List<int>();
for (var i = 2; i < 2; i++)
{
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
        divisors.Add(i);
    }
}
if (divisors.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("false " + String.Join(" ", divisors));
}
```

Comment: `for (var i = 2; i < 2; i++)` are you sure about that?

Comment: Another optimization: You only need to check up to n/2, but then add i as wall as n/i. At the end, add 1 and n, filter out dupes, done.

Comment: I believe if you add both `i` and `n / i` you only have to check up to the root of n (keep in mind this might not be an ordered list, and `n == 1` is a special case where 1 will get added to the list twice).

Comment: To widen the special case. It'll give dupes if `n` is divisable by it's root (but that case should be easy to check)

Comment: @AKX Thank you very much! ```c# (var i = 1; i < n; i++) ``` solves the problem together with ```c# if (divisors.Count <= 2) ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. You basically have to store your divisors somewhere or print them directly:

```
public static void Method(int n)
    {
        if (IsPrime(n))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{n} is a prime");
            return;
        }

        var divisors = new List<int>();

        for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                divisors.Add(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{n} isn't a prime");
        Console.WriteLine($"The divisors are: {string.Join(", ", divisors)}");
    }

    public static bool IsPrime(int n)
    {
        for(var i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to check primeness separately – if there are no divisors, it's a prime.

Comment: @AKX Not 100% true. He also want's the divisors 1 and the number itself. But instead of having a function IsPrime we could just calculate the divisors and check if the length of the list is greater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

From a brief inspection, there are two ways to generate the output. So far, you *count* the number of divisors, but neither *store* them nor *write* them to the output. You could replace

```
if (n % i == 0)
{
    a++;
}
```

by

```
if (n % i == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    a++;
}
```

or store the divisors in a

```
List<int>
```

to generate the output afterwards.